# Serpentine scan pattern generator

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

**Too-long, didn't read**

How can I generate ndarray indices so that for each new row, the index continues on the same column as the previous index. Like for the following image, but for an n-dimensional array. This is sometimes called a "serpentine", "snake-style" or "zig-zag" scan pattern.
[image: 2D snake-style indexing]

**Introduction**

`np.ndindex(shape)` yields an iterator of the indices to that array, like:

```py
>>> list(np.ndindex((3,3)))
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), 
 (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), 
 (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

I wish to generate the same indices, but in an order so that the next pixel is always adjacent to the previous. In its current form, ndindex continues from the first column with each new row. When the current row reaches the last column, I wish for it to continue from that same column but on the next row. I visualise this as "snake-style" (after the snake game) indexing (code snippet for this below*):

I can achieve this for a 2D array by reversing every second row:

```py
>>> shape = (3,3)
>>> A = list(np.ndindex(shape))
>>> A = np.reshape(A, shape + (len(shape), ))
>>> A[1::2] = A[1::2, ::-1]
>>> A.reshape((np.prod(shape), len(shape)))
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], 
 [1, 2], [1, 1], [1, 0], 
 [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
```

However, when I try to do this for a three-dimensional matrix, I run into problems. Here I use a slightly different approach to make plotting easier (using a single index).

[image: 3D Snake-style indexing]

One problem is that it does not appear that it is easy to generalize this to an ndimensional array due to the numpy slicing notation. The second problem is that for a 3D array, the second slice of the array begins at the bottom, and that row is either flipped left-right or not depending whether the size of that axes is odd or even.

Does anyone have a solution?

**Hard-coded array for the second figure

```py
data = np.array([
    [
        [0,1,2],
        [5,4,3],
        [6,7,8]],
    [
        [17,16,15],
        [12,13,14],
        [11,10,9]],
    [
        [18,19,20],
        [23,22,21],
        [24,25,26]]
])
fig, AX = plt.subplots(ncols=3)
for d, ax in zip(data, AX):
    ax.imshow(d, clim=(data.min(), data.max()), cmap='Greys')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility to either create an iterator or the entire array at once:

```
import numpy as np

def zigzagiter(dims):
    N = len(dims)
    idx = N*[0]
    drc = N*[1]
    while True:
        yield (*idx,)
        for j in reversed(range(N)):
            if idx[j] + drc[j] not in (-1, dims[j]):
                idx[j] += drc[j]
                break
            drc[j] *= -1
        else:
            break

def zigzag(dims):
    r = np.arange(np.prod(dims))
    out = []
    for d in dims:
        out.append(np.abs((1|((d+r)<<1))%(d<<2)-(d<<1))>>1)
        r //= d
    return np.transpose(out[::-1])
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = np.empty((3,3,3),int)
>>> a[tuple(zigzag((3,3,3)).T)] = np.arange(27)
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 5,  4,  3],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[17, 16, 15],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [11, 10,  9]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [23, 22, 21],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Comment: I timed `np.ndindex`, `zigzagiter` and `zigzag` with shape (512, 512, 50) by calling list() on the returned objects. The respective times were 6.08,  9.24 and 2.67 s. I don't one will be able to beat the generator times by much. Very well done!

Comment: @PaulPanzer - could you explain what the line `a[tuple(zigzag((3,3,3)).T)] = np.arange(27)` is doing? From what I understand, `zigzag` enumerates all possible combinations of row and column indices. How does the operation above "know" how to assign the elements in `np.arange(27)` into the object `a`?

Comment: @stats134711 `zigzag(...)` in the exmpl has `3` cols of height `27`, let's call them `I,J,K` we take the transpose,so `I,J,K` become rows.  The effect of casting to `tuple` is that the entire expression becomes equiv to `a[I,J,K]` which runs through the 27 elmts of `a` in the desired order.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks - I have two follow up questions, if you don't mind. Suppose we just focus on `I`, which is the first element of the `tuple`. Is it right that `I` will assign the elements of the first matrix in final object `a`? If so, how are the elements assigned in the order given by that first matrix?

Comment: @stats134711 Let me put it in a way that's unambiguous: `a[I[0],J[0],K[0]]==r.h.s.[0]`, `a[I[1],J[1],K[1]]==r.h.s.[1]` etc.

Comment: @PaulPanzer - Got it! Thanks!